# Collapse the ImageView inside CollapsingToolbarLayout until the content in the view is shown

Tags: android, imageview, hide, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to collapse the imageview inside CollapsingToolbarLayout until the content that is inside the activity is shown completely. At this time my imageview completely hides even after there is no content left in the view.

So here is what i want to achieve.

[Before scrolling the view image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpgKT.jpg)

[After scrolling the view image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmKFJ.png)

the image does not hide completely it gives collapse animation till the content is show completely. In my case the image completely hides.

Here is the xml code.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/expandedImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:src="@drawable/p10_image"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="content......"
                    android:textColor="#434343"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```